# Comprehensive exam in moodle

Tags: moodle

I need to build a Comprehensive Exam which is build of three main title and 10 Question in each title.

Is it possible to simulate a comprehensive exam with moodle?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_examination ?

The article notes that 'There is no standard definition for what such exams entail', so I would suggest that the answer is 'Yes', but it will depend on exactly what you are trying to achieve. The [quiz module](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Quiz_module) within Moodle is quite capable of creating a 3 page quiz, with 10 questions on each page (or it can be more than 3 pages, with some static text defining the break between the sections).

If, however, you are wanting to have separate grades for each of the sections, then you would probably have to split it across 3 quizzes (possibly using conditional availability to prevent access to the second & third quizzes until the first has been answered).